# I want to Auto populate a textfield with 2 different information's once the page is load

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Who can help me out please? I want to auto populate two different pieces of information into a single text field dynamically once the page is loaded. At the moment, I have something like this but its not working correctly:

```
<input type="text" id="success" 
             value="this is the message I want to render once the page 
             loads, this should be rendered with the ID(sucess)."/>
```

`id="success"` is the id of the second information I wish to grab and display in the textfield once the page is loaded. At the moment, once the page is loaded the `id="success"` dumps the exact information I want in the text-field but the `value="text i want"` won't show up.

My main objective is to display both `id="success"` + `value="text I want"` in the text-field once the page loads.

Comment: And what language are you using to try and populate this html element? Javascript (or jQuery) or are you using PHP?  You put both tags in your question, and without any of your current code work, it's hard to help you. Please provide the current code (JS or PHP) that you are trying to do this with.

Comment: At the moment, the code is in HTML, but from what am seeing HTML cant perform the tax, so JS (javascript) will be perfect for this. thanks JT Smith

Comment: Ok, I can help try to write something (using jQuery since I know that better than regular JS) but show me more of the HTML code.  On your current text field, you don't have any information so identifying that element will be difficult without knowing it's surrounding HTML.  I'll/you'll need to use like the `div` the text field is located in, in order to properly place the new text box.

Comment: Never mind, re-reading your question I realize you don't want to assign the `id` to the text field too.  That's just the name of the text field already. Let me see if I can write something for you real quick.

Comment: Thanks JT Smith, My Html Codes are like this:

Answer (score 0):

This is using jQuery.  If you aren't familiar with it (or even regular JS) then you need to check out [their site](http://jquery.com/)... or some [good books](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_1_6?url=search-alias=stripbooks&field-keywords=jquery&sprefix=jquery,aps,341) on programming JS.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#success').attr("value", "The text you want here");
}​);​
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9UGQ/) of this code in action.

Comment: Hi JT Smith, here is the clear description of my question, thanks for the effort to answer. [link](http://i1076.photobucket.com/albums/w458/cosmas2/example.jpg) the photobucket link is the clear description of what my form looks like.

Comment: the id to the red textfeild is id="success" and i called this Success id to the textfield above marked with green, that the reason why once the page is loads, the link in the textfeild (marked in red) is auto-populated in the textfeild(marked in green). now my problem is to get a text (The text i want) to populate in the textfeild(marked in green) once the page loads. this means that the both the Link and the text must be on page once the page loads. example check out the link [link](http://i1076.photobucket.com/albums/w458/cosmas2/example-1.jpg) so sorry for the stress. :)

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now.  So at the moment, you aren't having problems with the link loading like you want?  Also, where is the "text i want" coming from on the page?  In other words, why are you wanting to load it dynamically instead of having it static? I need to know where you are getting the "text i want" in order for JS to grab it and display it.  Also, to get a clearer picture of what everything looks like, it wouldn't hurt for you to post more code (especially the html) in your original question.

Comment: thanks JT, i just got it fixed. But having a diffrennt problem here. Am using html5 to validate a select feild, its working in all browser, except for internet. So am thinking JS will be the solution to this but not sure of the syntex. Mind to help me it. Thanks.